# エラー「minSdk（API24)>deviceSdk(API21)」の解消方法について

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studioにて実機との接続方法についてです。
minSdk（API24)>deviceSdk(API21)と表示され、実機と接続できません。

解決方法としてAndroidManifest.xmlで
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />`
の部分を書き換える方法を試して見たのですが、同じエラーが表示されてしまいます。
他に考えうる解決方法はどのようなものがあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

appディレクトリ以下にあるbuild.gradleファイルにて
minSdkVersionを指定する方法があります．

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html